# ORDER BY with a Union but a CASE in the "ORDER BY"

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query is producing the error: "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION..."

The only item I'm ordering by is Name which is in the Select list.  I'm guessing the CASE demands additional syntax. The Case in this case makes sure those two names are listed first. The second Select adds a blank field first.

```
 SELECT Name FROM Name 
 UNION 
 SELECT ''
 ORDER BY   
 CASE Name 
 WHEN 'John' THEN 1 
 WHEN 'Frank' THEN 2 
 ELSE 3 END
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty explicit.  How about using a subquery?

```
SELECT n.*
FROM (SELECT Name FROM Name 
      UNION 
      SELECT ''
     ) n
ORDER BY (CASE Name 
             WHEN 'John' THEN 1 
             WHEN 'Frank' THEN 2 
             ELSE 3
          END);
```

If your tables do not have duplicates, you should use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks! But that query does not produce a blank row first.

Comment: @Borges Why would you expect a blank row first?

Comment: It populates a drop down list which needs a blank default row.

Comment: @Borges Need and expect are not the same.

Comment: @Borges . . . If you want the empty string value to be first, then look at the `ORDRE BY`.  You have explicitly put all the other values (including blank) after the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Or just include it in your query as a separate field

```
SELECT Name, 
       CASE Name 
           WHEN 'John' THEN 1 
           WHEN 'Frank' THEN 2 
           ELSE 3 END as Order 
FROM Name 
 UNION 
 SELECT '', 3
 ORDER BY Order
```

Comment: That produces two columns. I just want a list of names with a blank row first and those two names after that.

Comment: use the other method then.. and add `When '' THEN 0`  or wrap this in a subquery and select just name and `Select '',0`

Answer (score 0):

```
create table ##t (nname nvarchar(100) not null);

insert into ##t
values 
    ('tom'),
    ('dick'),
    ('harry');

select nname 
from ( select nname 
       from ##t 
       union
       select '' 
     ) tt
 order by ( case nname 
                WHEN ''     THEN 0 
                WHEN 'tom'  THEN 1 
                WHEN 'dick' THEN 2 
                ELSE 3 
           END
         )
```